# Custom http method handling with Spark Java

Tags: java, spark-java

Is there any way or any intention for future releases to handle custom HTTP methods in [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/)? I need to handle PURGE requests (even though is not in the official HTTP RFC 2616 and RFCs 7230-7235 specs it's used by products like varnish or nginx).

In the meantime I had to use [Jadler](https://github.com/jadler-mocking) to implement a specific endpoint, but would be really nice if I could use Spark for all my endpoints.